# Как извлечь значение из хеша

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте у меня есть такая вакханалия. Как мне отсортровать сие чудо по "filter"?

```
 ab =  {"Кирпично-красный"=>[{"url"=>nil,
         "hex"=>"B10101",
         "filter"=>"Красный"}, ["000057233", "000022147"]]
       "Ярко-синий"=>[{"url"=>nil,
         "hex"=>"114C9C",
         "filter"=>"Синий"}, ["000040233", "000052147"]]
      "Клубнично-красный"=>[{"url"=>nil,
         "hex"=>"D10800",
        "filter"=>"Красный"}
      "Лаванда"=>[{"url"=>nil,
        "hex"=>"E6E6FA", 
        "filter"=>"Синий"}, ["000033166"]]
```

В результате получилось чтобы такое :

```
 ab =  {"Кирпично-красный"=>[{"url"=>nil,
         "hex"=>"B10101",
         "filter"=>"Красный"},  ["000057233", "000022147"]]
      "Клубнично-красный"=>[{"url"=>nil,
         "hex"=>"D10800",
        "filter"=>"Красный"}, ["000047356", "000012891"]
       "Ярко-синий"=>[{"url"=>nil,
         "hex"=>"114C9C",
         "filter"=>"Синий"}, ["000040233", "000052147"]]
      "Лаванда"=>[{"url"=>nil,
        "hex"=>"E6E6FA", 
        "filter"=>"Синий"}, ["000033166"]]
```

Comment: Я пытаюсь это сделать так   ab.sort_by{|v, k| v[0]["filter"]} Но что-то не выходит

Comment: В смысле, отсортировать? У вас же не массив, а хэш. Он не предназначен для хранения определённого порядка (хотя способен на это).

Comment: Я понимаю,но, к сожалению, такие данные получаю.

Comment: Дело не в исходных данных, а в том, какой результат вам в конечном итоге нужен.

Comment: Это маленьки кусочек, того, что есть, filter - цвет, к которому принадлежат названия ключей(т.е ключ может быть Бордовый, но родитель у него Красный, т.е  фильтр), и нужно выстроить по алфавиту именно цвета в filter

Comment: Пример результата приведите. Для исходных данных, указанных в вопросе.

Comment: я не буду писать весь код, вырву только "filter". {..."filter"=>"Белый"...} {..."filter"=>"Черный"...} {.."filter"=>"Зеленый"...} {..."filter"=>"Красный"...} . Нужно,чтобы они были в порядке таком {..."filter"=>"Белый"...} {..."filter"=>"Черный"...}{.."filter"=>"Зеленый"...} {..."filter"=>"Красный"...} . Если,я конечно правильно понял вас

Comment: Только допишите пример в **вопрос** и не для каких-то данных, а для данных в самом вопросе. Если нужно, обновите их.

Comment: Сами ключи получается сортировать, а значения - ни в какую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ab.sort_by{|v, k| v[0]["filter"]}` не работает, так как порядок k и v перепутан.
Полагаю, что sort

```
ab.sort{|a, b| a[1][0]['filter'] <=> b[1][0]['filter']}.to_h
```

будет быстрее в данном случае, чем sort_by

```
ab.sort_by{|key,value| value[0]['filter']}.to_h
```

Если у вас речь про большое количество данных, то сделайте benchmark на всякий случай.

Comment: Ругается,**syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting =>** и **syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input**

Comment: @Litrein, у вас на самом деле в примере хэша синтаксические ошибки, но я их поправила, прежде чем пробовать в консоли

Comment: Спасибо,я наверно, когда Ctrl+C/V делал напутал.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, узнал я как этот чудо-юдо Хеш образуется, парень его мержил из двух,в одном

```
 {"Кирпично-красный"=>{"url"=>nil,"hex"=>"B10101","filter"=>"Красный"}
```

В другом

```
      {"Кирпично-красный"=>["000057233", "000022147"]]}
```

В итоге,отсортировал первый Хеш, и смержил со вторым, получилось то,что хотел